# Check if existing node element instance satisfies an xpath condition

Tags: php, xpath, bdd, behat, mink

Executing an xpath query can return us a node, a node attribute, function result, etc. Executing an xpath in Mink must return a node element in `find()`, `findAll()` and `has()` methods of `NodeElement` class.

There are situations when we have a selected node element and we want to make assertions that it has a class or that some xpath expression on that element satisfies a condition.

What would be the proper and most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath we can reference the element itself using the `self` axis. The idea is to select self with the required condition, if its satisfied Mink will get the same element (not function or expression result, or attribute, or anything else), thus won't throw an exception.

```
$element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('//div');
$element->has('/self::*[position() = 1]');
$element->has('/self::*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " my-class ")]');
```